gstreamer: no element 'autovideosrc' in c++ project on macOS
I get the error: no element "autovideosrc" when I run this program:
#include <iostream>
#include "gst/gst.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) 
{
    gst_init(&argc, const_cast<char***>( &argv ));
    
    auto command = "autovideosrc ! autovideosink";
    
    GError *err = nullptr;
    auto pipeline = gst_parse_launch(command, &err);
   
    if (!pipeline)
    {
        std::cerr << err->message << "\n";
        return -1;
    }
    
    gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
    std::cin.ignore();
    
    return 0;
}

when I run gst-inspect-1.0 autovideosrc in a terminal it shows that the element is available. How to fix the error in the program?
